# Dynamically select a template based on an environment variable in Azure YAML Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Following script works if BuildReason is defined as user defined variable within the yml file. Would it be possible to get its value if it is set as environment variable directly on the UI?

```
trigger: none

name: $(Date:yyyy).$(Date:MMdd).$(Rev:r)

variables:

- name: templateName
  ${{ if eq( variables['BuildReason'], 'PR' ) }}:
    value: 'pipelines/prvalidation-template.yml'
  ${{ else }}:
    value: 'pipelines/build-template.yml'

extends:

  template: ${{ variables.templateName }}

  parameters:
      Parameter1: MyProject
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is already a system field that contains this information. Look at `Build.Reason`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is predefined variable [`Build.Reason`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) which you can use in expressions.

[image]

Comment: @ssh could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?